# Yammer Analytics Data Export

Tags: api, analytics, business-intelligence, yammer, powerbi

I want to create some dashboards and reports based on the yammer data. I found a interesting link to get through this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2014/04/09/yammer-analytics-with-excel-and-power-bi.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

I am performing the same steps as mentioned in the above link but there is some issue with yammer export processor (https://yammer.azurewebsites.net/) as when I am selecting my network it throughs an error for saying "error validating user as a network admin
[image]

Does anybody has idea related to the issue or any other method to export data from yammer.

Thanks
Piyush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the yammer.azurewebsites.net site is a project site that the author of the referenced MSDN blog constructed, and as such is a personal project for demonstration purposes, not a part of the Yammer service.

To export data from Yammer you can either do it from the Admin interface in Yammer or use the API, documented at this link https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/data-export-api. You must be a verified admin to use the data export.

Comment: Hi Naomi, I got your point and I am doing the same, but I want some more insightful data, for ex:- likes, shares, sentiments...for which I am using this link.

Comment: Sure I do understand Piyush. I think you'll see some new stuff/improvements in a month at Ignite for the availability of data for analytics, so it might be worth keeping an eye out for that if you can wait that long to know what is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do that if you're just a regular user.  The export function of Yammer requires you to be an Admin.  http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2848223.

-Lukasz

Comment: Hi @Lukasz P, I am a regular user as well as the network admin, even i have checked with main admin who has all the rights for the network, he is also getting the same issue, my question is, this the problem with Yammer Export Processor API or something else, as i have found that many others users are also getting the same issue, but not get the correct answer

Comment: Good information.  I'll see what I can dig up to get you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the site uses the data export API, the user initiating the export must be a "verified admin" on the Yammer network. There is another permissions level called "network admin", which sometimes causes confusion.

See "Admin level rights" at:
https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Yammer-admin-guide-a9c206d4-fb18-4250-bec6-e783b926e4f6